# How to get crash logs of Chrome extension?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Is there a way to get logs about Chrome extension crash?

I have extension that crashes only when use it from Chrome Store (works fine in dev mode). But I cannot identify the reason of crash, because it crashes immediately after open extension's popup. Message:

```
This extension may have been corrupted.
```

I have already tried to [run Chrome with enabled logs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12233986/7597651), but it gives no info about crash of my extension.

Comment: You can attach a debugger like Visual Studio to the extension process so that the debugger intercepts the fatal exception and shows a stack trace (call stack) which might be helpful to diagnose the cause.

Comment: Using such debugger looks like reverse engineering. Is it really no adequate way to get the proper error message from chrome?

Comment: @wOxxOm Thanks for advice, it can help someone. However attaching of debugger could be painful if, for example, code is obfuscated and without source map. Also there are could be error which isn't related to extension's code but related to Chrome (e.g https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45663062/chrome-extension-corrupted-when-open-popup). In such cases debugging is pointless and only some logs can give you a reason.