# Chrome Extension devtools panel no longer appearing after crash

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I am developing a chrome extension but then it suddenly crashed. Removing and re adding the directory via Debug mode in chrome://extensions, I see the button appearing, however when I close chrome and reopen and inspect a page, the extension panel is no longer there.

Is there some sort of timer that prevents a crashing chrome extension to show up in the devtools panel?

```
{
    "name": "test",
    "version": "0.0122",
    "description": "test",
    "devtools_page": "devtools.html",
    "background": {
        "scripts": [
            "scripts/background.js"                       
        ]
    },
    "permissions": [
        "tabs",
        "storage",
        "background"]
}
```

before the crash the devtools panel would show up when I inspect a page. After the crash, it will no longer appear, even after removing the chrome extension and adding the folder again. I restarted the chrome browser but still does not appear.

update: when i checked the task manager I was surprised there was a chrome.exe using up 5 gigs of memory!!! when I closed it everything is working fine.

I'm not sure why this is happening and how to go about debugging this error.

Comment: In case this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12233986

Comment: I woudl accept that as an answer

Comment: OK, posted an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure of the exact cause, but see https://stackoverflow.com/a/12233986 for tips on debugging a Chrome extension.